# How do I pass an object from the Index view to the edit view using MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a simple WCF service that is to be configured by an MVC3 UI.

When I call the index page from my controller, I want to display the values held in the configuration, which has been returned by the service. The user could then chose to edit these settings and then send them back to the service.

I want to do something like this in the index view ...

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", model)
</div>
```

and then consume the model in the controller like this...

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit( SettingsModel Config)
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> configErrors = null;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Set up a channel factory to use the webHTTPBinding
                using (WebChannelFactory<IChangeService> serviceChannel = new WebChannelFactory<IChangeService>(new Uri(baseServiceUrl)))
                {
                    IChangeService channel = serviceChannel.CreateChannel();
                    configErrors = channel.SetSysConfig(Config);
                }
          }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

but this doesn't work.

Any suggestions???

Comment: Could you explain which part does not work? At least to me its not very clear

Comment: Are you facing issues in passing the "model" object from View to the action method "Edit"?

Comment: @PawanMishra, This is exactly the problem I have. I don't seem to be able to pass the model from the index into the settings view.

Comment: @RonSijm, the actual error is that "model" doesn't exist in the current context on the index view.

Comment: @TeamWild : Looking at your code snippet, I can see that from your Index view, you are calling "Edit" action and trying to pass "SettingsModel" object. From here, you are again redirecting to "Index" view. Its in the passing of "SettingsModel" object, that you are facing issues.If yes, then see my answer. If not, then may be I am missing something.

Comment: @PawanMishra, I'm still learning MVC (quite slowly it appears ;o) and the code to redirect to the index view is a cut and paste from an MVC tutorial on the asp.net website. I could be going at this completely wrong but all I want to do is display the "SettingsModel" contents and allow the user to edit it and then send it back.

Comment: I have updated my answer. What you are looking for is a strongly typed View and a "ViewModel" driven approach, wherein the data between view and action is being passed as strongly typed model object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form gets posted, all the input type fields data is collected and sent to the server. You can see this data using FireBug. The key point here is that, is the data that is being posted in a form, that MVC's default model binder can understand and map it to the model object, which is being passed as input parameter to the action method.

In your case, the model is of type "SettingsModel". You have to ensure that, the form data that is being posted is in format, that can be mapped to the "SettingsModel" object.

Same kind of question discussed in another thread : [Can't figure out why model is null on postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026868/cant-figure-out-why-model-is-null-on-postback/8026934#8026934)

Check Out this article : [NerdDinner Step 6: ViewData and ViewModel](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part6.htm)

In the above article, carefully go through the "Using a ViewModel Pattern" section. My guess is that, this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to post the values to populate the SettingsModel object on the Edit action. You can do this using hidden form fields if you don't want the user to see it. Otherwise you could have no parameters on the Edit action and make another call to the web service to populate the Settings model.